# Connecting to Docker MySQL using MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, magento, docker, ssh

I am attempting to connect to a database on a Docker container through MySQL Workbench, though I am unsure what exactly I should be inserting into the following fields:

SSH Hostname (tried localhost:3306 & 8001 and 0.0.0.0:3306 & 8001)
SSH Username

MySQL Hostname: left as 127.0.0.1
MySQL Server port: 3306

My DB name, username and password are all "magento".

Guessing it's just the SSH info that is incorrect. Could someone assist here?

### Docker PS result

Due to the project I am working on, company and client names have been removed

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                           NAMES
25da671f766d        mageinferno/magento2-nginx:1.11-1   "/usr/local/bin/st..."   5 hours ago         Up 4 hours          443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp   CLIENTaws_app_1
f1f7fb0e7174        COMPANY/magento2-php:7.0-fpm       "docker-php-entryp..."   5 hours ago         Up 4 hours          9000/tcp                        CLIENTaws_phpfpm_1
69388c2ce5c7        percona:5.7                         "docker-entrypoint..."   5 hours ago         Up 4 hours          0.0.0.0:8001->3306/tcp          CLIENTaws_db_1
```

Comment: Cold you show what returns `docker ps` command?

Comment: @BukharovSergey Added, though I have had to replace our company and client names. Hope that's enough?

Comment: thank you, that enough. Your destination port is 8001 .  Please try to connect using mysql-client with commnad `mysql -umagento -pmagento -P8001 --protocol=tcp`

Comment: @BukharovSergey I am able to connect using that command, though still unsure how to connect using Workbench

Comment: i understood, But i wanna to check that mysql works properly and can be reached. Workbench settings must be: `connection method`: `Standart (TCP\IP)`, `hostname`: `127.0.0.1`, `port`: `8001`, `username`: `magento`, `password`: `magento`. It must works if you can connect to mysql via console mysql client

Comment: @BukharovSergey Simple as that! That works. Feel free to add that as an answer if you want and I'll accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You settings must be:

- connection method: Standart (TCP\IP),
- hostname: 127.0.0.1,
- port: 8001,
- username: magento,
- password: magento